# Управление ссылками посредством jQuery

Tags: jquery, ссылки

Функция

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(c) { ...
    ... c(".tclass").each(function(d) { ...}
}
```

подхватывает ссылки из списка (ul) определенного класса (.tclass).
Как сделать поддержку еще ссылок из другого списка (например .zclass)? Дописать аналогичную функцию, но с указанием другого класса или можно вставить дополнительное условие в эту функцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить новые элементы можно функцией .add("selector");
На примере:

```
$(".tclass").add(".zclass").each(...);
```

Comment: Или $(".tclass, .zclass").each(...);

Comment: Да, спасибо, - работает.

Comment: Примите ответ как правильный, раз помогло, что бы не висел неотвеченный.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").each();
```

Ну это очевидно - подхватит все возможные ссылки на странице. Но Вам нужно задать некую закономерность этих ссылок, и придумать на основе этой закономерности алгоритм подхвата нужных вам ссылок. Ведь вам может понабодится еще и другая группа ссылок с другим классом, а потом еще и еще, но каждый раз Вы же не будете вписывать в код название классов.

Старайтесь универсализировать.